# Catching python execution error in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

My matlab program will generate a python file and kick it off. Due to various reasons some time the generated python file will run into error. Lacking time right now to debug that part I want to be able to catch in matlab when a python file fail to execute complete so I can just rerun the function with a different random input.

So how do I detect an error on the python file that was kicked off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `try-catch-end` like this.

```matlab
while true
  try
    yourcodeofpython;
    break;
  catch e
    if isa(e,'matlab.exception.PyException')
      % e.message % or something to log the error
    end
    continue;
  end
end
```

which will only end if the Python is finished, and will restart if get an exception.
`isa(e,'matlab.exception.PyException')` is to check whether it's Python Exception or not.

[Official Docs about this](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_external/handle-python-exceptions.html)